# RXJS subject take the first value on every changes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an event and it will emit the event for 1 and/or 2 times, depending on the selection. Every time I am trying to capture the first event. Below is my html code

```
<custom-dropdown (customClick)="makeSubject($event)">
</custom-dropdown>
```

Angular code

```
dropdownSubject = new Subject<any>();

    
constructor(){
    this.dropdownSubject.pipe(
        take(1))
        .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('rs.type ', res);
    }); 
}

makeSubject(event){
    this.dropdownSubject.next(event);
}
```

with above code it is triggering only one time (on first changes), if I change the dropdown for the next time it is not triggering.

Instead of the `take(1)` I put `debounceTime(300)` and I can see the console log getting printed, but every time it is giving the last value.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-challenge-14-solution-gmaqak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the below screen shot,
`take 1st value` is printing only on the first time, but I want to print it every time (on every click)

[image]

Comment: You probably want [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)

Comment: @ertucode I tried it but it is not working :(

Comment: What behavior do you want?

Comment: @BizzyBob I want to take first value every on every changes. I have added the images and updated the stackblitz as well.

Comment: chatGPT spits out `throttleTime(300, undefined, { leading: true })` which seems to work. I won't post as answer as this is a new operator to me and chatGPT is banned.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thanks, it is working as expected :-). But I am just wondering why the `take` or `first` operator is not working on the next time. It will be great if you explain this as an answer..

Comment: @mkHun 3 points to understand 
- Point-1:  adding take(1) removes subscription after first value is recieved so it will complete subject no more subscription will be active.
- Point-2: Adding debounce or throttle means -> subscription will get value after certain delay e.g 300 ms so it will always catch 2nd value although emitted both.
- Point-3 In Order to get both values just remove take(1) from code and don't delay debounceTime too it will work as expected =>  "print it every time (on every click)"